# How to specify the shape of results with WebApi2, OData with $expand

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, automapper, entity-framework-6

I have a problem executing my AutoMapper mappings when using OData with specific `$select` or `$expand` values.

Using the WebApi Action:

```
    public IQueryable<BookInRequestDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<BookInRequest> query)
    {
        var results = query.ApplyTo(_context.BookInRequests) as IQueryable<BookInRequest>;
        var mappedResults = Mapper.Map<IQueryable<BookInRequest>, IQueryable<BookInRequestDto>>(results);
        return mappedResults;
    }
```

When I query: `api/Get`, I get an appropriate response, but a Document's `Properties` is set to `null` response containing documents properties set to null.

When I query: `api/Get?$expand=Documents/Properties`, the response is an empty array.

As I understand, this is because Select/Expand changes the shape of the response, so it no longer matches an IQueryable of BookInRequest, and instead returns an IQueryable.

I'm happy to return that, except I need to be able to apply the AutoMapper Mappings.  Is there anything that can be done to enforce the shape of the query results?

I have the following entities:

```
public class BookInRequest {
    //...
    public virtual ICollection<BookInDocument> Documents { get; set; }
}

public class BookInDocument {
    public ICollection<BookInDocumentProperty> Properties { get; set; }     
}
```

With Corresponding DTO's that are pretty much identical, except for the `BookInDocumentDto`:

```
public class BookInDocumentDto {
    public dynamic Properties { get; set; }
}
```

My Mapping definition is as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<BookInRequest, BookInRequestDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<BookInDocument, BookInDocumentDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Properties, 
          y => y.MapFrom(z => 
                   DynamicHelpers.PropertiesAsDynamic(z.Properties)));
```