# Using DTO's with OData & Web API

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata, automapper

Using Web API and OData, I have a service which exposes Data Transfer Objects instead of the Entity Framework entities.

I use AutoMapper to transform the EF Entities into their DTO counter parts using `ProjectTo()`:

```
public class SalesOrdersController : ODataController
{
    private DbContext _DbContext;

    public SalesOrdersController(DbContext context)
    {
        _DbContext = context;
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<SalesOrderDto> Get(ODataQueryOptions<SalesOrderDto> queryOptions)
    {
        return _DbContext.SalesOrders.ProjectTo<SalesOrderDto>(AutoMapperConfig.Config);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<SalesOrderDto> Get([FromODataUri] string key, ODataQueryOptions<SalesOrderDto> queryOptions)
    {
        return _DbContext.SalesOrders.Where(so => so.SalesOrderNumber == key)
                            .ProjectTo<SalesOrderDto>(AutoMapperConfig.Config);
    }
}
```

AutoMapper (V4.2.1) is configured as follows, note the `ExplicitExpansion()` which prevents serialisation auto expanding navigation properties when they are not requested:

```
cfg.CreateMap<SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDto>()                
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SalesOrderLines, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());

cfg.CreateMap<SalesOrderLine, SalesOrderLineDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.MasterStockRecord, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SalesOrderHeader, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());
```

`ExplicitExpansion()` then creates a new problem where the following request throws an error:

> **/odatademo/SalesOrders('123456')?$expand=SalesOrderLines**
>
> The query specified in the URI is not valid. The specified type member 'SalesOrderLines' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

The navigation property `SalesOrderLines` is unknown to EF so this error is pretty much what I expected to happen.  The question is, how do I handle this type of request?

The `ProjectTo()` method does have an overload that allows me to pass in an array of properties that require expansion, I found & modified the extension method `ToNavigationPropertyArray` to try and parse the request into a string array:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<SalesOrderDto> Get([FromODataUri] string key, ODataQueryOptions<SalesOrderDto> queryOptions)
{
    return _DbContext.SalesOrders.Where(so => so.SalesOrderNumber == key)
            .ProjectTo<SalesOrderDto>(AutoMapperConfig.Config, null, queryOptions.ToNavigationPropertyArray());
}

public static string[] ToNavigationPropertyArray(this ODataQueryOptions source)
{
    if (source == null) { return new string[]{}; }

    var expandProperties = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.SelectExpand?.RawExpand) ? new List<string>().ToArray() : source.SelectExpand.RawExpand.Split(',');

    for (var expandIndex = 0; expandIndex < expandProperties.Length; expandIndex++)
    {
        // Need to transform the odata syntax for expanding properties to something EF will understand:

        // OData may pass something in this form: "SalesOrderLines($expand=MasterStockRecord)";                
        // But EF wants it like this: "SalesOrderLines.MasterStockRecord";

        expandProperties[expandIndex] = expandProperties[expandIndex].Replace(" ", "");
        expandProperties[expandIndex] = expandProperties[expandIndex].Replace("($expand=", ".");
        expandProperties[expandIndex] = expandProperties[expandIndex].Replace(")", "");
    }

    var selectProperties = source.SelectExpand == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source.SelectExpand.RawSelect) ? new List<string>().ToArray() : source.SelectExpand.RawSelect.Split(',');

    //Now do the same for Select (incomplete)          
    var propertiesToExpand = expandProperties.Union(selectProperties).ToArray();

    return propertiesToExpand;
}
```

This works for expand, so now I can handle a request like the following:

> **/odatademo/SalesOrders('123456')?$expand=SalesOrderLines**

or a more complicated request like:

> **/odatademo/SalesOrders('123456')?$expand=SalesOrderLines($expand=MasterStockRecord)**

However, more complicated request that try to combine $select with $expand will fail:

> **/odatademo/SalesOrders('123456')?$expand=SalesOrderLines($select=OrderQuantity)**
>
> Sequence contains no elements

So, the question is: am I approaching this the right way?
It feels very smelly that I would have to write something to parse and transform the ODataQueryOptions into something EF can understand.

It seems this is a rather popular topic:

- [odata-expand-dtos-and-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323545/odata-expand-dtos-and-entity-framework)
- [how-to-specify-the-shape-of-results-with-webapi2-odata-with-expand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20462444/how-to-specify-the-shape-of-results-with-webapi2-odata-with-expand)
- [web-api-queryable-how-to-apply-automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484692/web-api-queryable-how-to-apply-automapper)
- [how-do-i-map-an-odata-query-against-a-dto-to-another-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628521/how-do-i-map-an-odata-query-against-a-dto-to-another-entity)

While most of these suggest using `ProjectTo`, none seem to address serialisation auto expanding properties, or how to handle expansion if `ExplictExpansion` has been configured.

**Classes and Config below:**

Entity Framework (V6.1.3) entities:

```
public class SalesOrderHeader
{
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Alpha { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderLine> SalesOrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrderLine
{
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string OrderLineNumber { get; set; }        
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesOrderHeader SalesOrderHeader { get; set; }
    public virtual MasterStockRecord MasterStockRecord { get; set; }
}

public class MasterStockRecord
{        
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }     
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

OData (V6.13.0) Data Transfer Objects:

```
public class SalesOrderDto
{
    [Key]
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SalesOrderLineDto> SalesOrderLines { get; set; }
}

public class SalesOrderLineDto
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("SalesOrderHeader")]
    public string SalesOrderNumber { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public string OrderLineNumber { get; set; }
    public string LineType { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderQuantity { get; set; }

    public virtual SalesOrderDto SalesOrderHeader { get; set; }
    public virtual StockDto MasterStockRecord { get; set; }
}

public class StockDto
{
    [Key]
    public string StockCode { get; set; }        
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

OData Config:

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

builder.EntitySet<StockDto>("Stock");
builder.EntitySet<SalesOrderDto>("SalesOrders");
builder.EntitySet<SalesOrderLineDto>("SalesOrderLines");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never really managed to work this one out.  The `ToNavigationPropertyArray()` extension method helps a little, but does not handle infinite depth navigation.

The real solution is to create Actions or Functions to allow clients to request data requiring a more complicated query.

The other alternative is to make multiple smaller/simple calls then aggregate the data on the client, but this isn't really ideal.

Answer (score 3):

I have created an Automapper explicit navigation expansion utility function that should work with N-deph expands. Posting it here since it might help someone.

```
public List<string> ProcessExpands(IEnumerable<SelectItem> items, string parentNavPath="")
{
    var expandedPropsList = new List<String>();
    if (items == null) return expandedPropsList;

    foreach (var selectItem in items)
    {
        if (selectItem is ExpandedNavigationSelectItem)
        {
            var expandItem = selectItem as ExpandedNavigationSelectItem;
            var navProperty = expandItem.PathToNavigationProperty?.FirstSegment?.Identifier;

            expandedPropsList.Add($"{parentNavPath}{navProperty}");                    
            //go recursively to subproperties
            var subExpandList = ProcessExpands(expandItem?.SelectAndExpand?.SelectedItems, $"{parentNavPath}{navProperty}.");
            expandedPropsList =  expandedPropsList.Concat(subExpandList).ToList();
        }
    }
    return expandedPropsList;
}
```

You can call it with :

```
var navExp = ProcessExpands(options?.SelectExpand?.SelectExpandClause?.SelectedItems)
```

it will return a list with `["Parent" ,"Parent.Child"]`

Comment: Note: remeber to convert the result to an array with `ToArray()` before pass to AutoMapper `ProjectTo()` method because it accept a param array argument.

Comment: Your expansion only works with 2 levels of nesting @Ovidiu Buligan. When I have more depth (grand-children) the laevels are not prepended.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to mark something for explicit expansion in AutoMapper, you need to also opt-back-in when calling `ProjectTo<>()`.

```
// map
cfg.CreateMap<SalesOrderHeader, SalesOrderDto>()                
   .ForMember(dest => dest.SalesOrderLines, opt => opt.ExplicitExpansion());

// updated controller
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<SalesOrderDto> Get()
{
    return _dbContext.SalesOrders
        .ProjectTo<SalesOrderDto>(
            AutoMapperConfig.Config, 
            so => so.SalesOrderLines,
            // ... additional opt-ins
        );
}
```

While the [AutoMapper wiki](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions#explicit-expansion) does state this, the example is perhaps a little misleading by not including the paired `ExplicitExpansion()` call.

> To control which members are expanded during projection, set  ExplicitExpansion in the configuration **and then** pass in the members you want to explicitly expand:

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm already explicitly expanding the navigation properties. The code above shows the code I use to configure this & parse the odata to obtain which navigation properties require expansion. That is the purpose of `ToNavigationPropertyArray()` extension method, the result of which then gets passed to the `ProjectTo()`. My question was/is about whether using the extension method to parse the odata query string was the right approach because it gets messy if multiple navigation properties need expanding. I worked around it by using actions & functions for more complicated queries.